# Do I need 2 Comparer<T> for sorting in both directions?

Tags: c#, sorting, .net-4.0

If I create a `Comparer<T>` for the purposes of sorting a set of objects, is there a simple way to 'invert' it so I can sort in the other direction? Or do I need to define a 2nd `Comparer<T>` with the tests in the Compare method swapped around?

Comment: http://linqcomparer.codeplex.com/ please try using a lamba compararer (Or using Linq as suggested). Reversing a list has a pointless performance overhead

Comment: Well, it seems the _simple_ but costly solution is to use .Reverse but I guess the better way would be to use the suggested Linq option (and I take MerikOWA's point about using OrderByDescending).

Comment: @DaveBish thanks for the pointer; I'll have a look at that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class ReverseComparer<T> : Comparer<T>
{
    private Comparer<T> inputComparer;
    public ReverseComparer(Comparer<T> inputComparer)
    {
        this.inputComparer = inputComparer;
    }

    public override int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        return inputComparer.Compare(y, x);
    }
}
```

This allows you to do something like:

```
list.Sort(new ReverseComparer(someOtherComparer));
```

Comment: **+1** Nice out of the box thinking! (I don't like creating `Comparer<T>` at all, but it very nice!

Comment: @Servy. This is the one I've gone for. Thanks. I decided to go this route as there are _n_ comparer's needed and the one used is based on a set of conditionals. Your solution is nice 'cos I can have a single conditional at the end of my tests; `if(doReverse) result = new ReverseComparer(result);`

Comment: This came from me spending the time to re-implement the LINQ orderBy for fun.  After creating something like this the implementation of `OrderByDecending(data, comparer)` becomes nothing more than a call to `OrderByAscending(data, new ReverseComparer(comparer))`.

Comment: With the new .NET 4.5 there's an alternative way: `Comparer<>.Create` It goes something like this: `var reverseComp = Comparer<T>.Create((x, y) => comp.Compare(y, x));`

Answer (score 4):

It's not the efficent code, but you can use `Reverse` after sort with the `Comparer<T>`:

```
var ordered = theList.Sort(new FooComparer()).Reverse();
```

---

Since you tagger your question `.Net4`
You can use `LINQ` `OrderBy` and `ThenBy`, so you don't need even one `Comparer<T>`...

```
var ordered = theList.OrderBy(x => x.First).ThenBy(x => x.Second);
var reverseOrdered = theList.OrderByDescending(x => x.First)
                            .ThenByDescending(x => x.Second);
```

Comment: reverseOrder is different than changing the order you compare columns, maybe you meant to use OrderByDescending?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same `Comparer<T>`, just when you need the result inverted you can simply use `myList<T>.Reverse()` method.