# SortedDictionary in reverse order of keys

Tags: c#, linq, reverse, sorteddictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
SortedDictionary<int, string> dictionary = new SortedDictionary<int, string>();
dictionary.add(2007, "test1");
dictionary.add(2008, "test2");
dictionary.add(2009, "test3");
dictionary.add(2010, "test4");
dictionary.add(2011, "test5");
dictionary.add(2012, "test6");
```

I'd like to reverse the order of the elements so that when I display the items on the screen, I can start with 2012.  I'd like to reassign the reversed dictionary back to the variable dictionary if possible.

I tried `dictionary.Reverse` but that doesn't seem to be working as easily as I thought.

Comment: Create a new `SortedDictionary` with a reversed comparer.

Comment: Could you give me an example of this please? It sounds like it's what I'm looking for.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539525/do-i-need-2-comparert-for-sorting-in-both-directions

Comment: There is no "Sort" method on the dictionary unfortunately. I had already looked for it. ... Also, I'd like to not write extra code or classes if possible.  This seems like something that should be easily done with LINQ.

Comment: 1) You don't need a `Sort` method. You just need the same comparer approach as that other question 2) No LINQ won't help you. You need a custom comparer. LINQ will give you an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` not a `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

Comment: The `Reverse` extension method doesn't change your dictionary. It simply foreach-es through it and then yields the elements in opposite order. You could use it like `foreach (var intStringPair in dictionary.Reverse()) { SomehowDisplay(intStringPair); }` But also see the answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can give `SortedDictionary` an `IComparer<TKey>` on construction. You just need to provide one which reverses the order. For example:

```
public sealed class ReverseComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    private readonly IComparer<T> original;

    public ReverseComparer(IComparer<T> original)
    {
        // TODO: Validation
        this.original = original;
    }

    public int Compare(T left, T right)
    {
        return original.Compare(right, left);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
var dictionary = new SortedDictionary<int, string>(
       new ReverseComparer<int>(Comparer<int>.Default));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Using this, how am I getting the original dictionary into the newly created one?

Comment: @AdamLevitt: It's not clear what you're trying to do. This would be *instead* of the original code. Just add the values into this dictionary. Do you actually need the dictionary in its original order as well?

Comment: @AdamLevitt You don't. The `Comparer` property of `SortedDictionary` is read-only, and can't be changed after construction.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - Thanks for the help.  So, I create the dictionary as displayed above.  Once I have the entries in there, I just want to do the reverse and I'll never need the original again.  Once I put the values into this dictionary, do I need to make another call to actually do the reverse action?

Comment: @AdamLevitt: Why do you want to reverse it *afterwards*? The point of the code in my answer is that you create the dictionary so that the entries will *always* be in descending order, automatically, with no further action required.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - This did it! I understand completely.  However, the constructor should be modified in your answer to say "this.original = original"... and thanks!

Comment: @AdamLevitt: Yup, that was a dumb typo. Glad it's working for you.

Comment: @AdamLevitt In .NET 4.5 you can even do it without writing the class yourself (see my alternative answer).

Comment: You can do something like this :                                                                  var sortedDict=new SortedDictionary<string,int>(); sortedDict.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Value);

Comment: @robert: No, calling OrderByDescending and ignoring the return value won't do anything.

Answer (score 19):

If you're using the newest version of the framework, .NET 4.5 (Visual Studio 2012), you can do it very easily with `Comparer<>.Create`. It's like this:

```
var dictionary =
  new SortedDictionary<int, string>(Comparer<int>.Create((x, y) => y.CompareTo(x)));
```

Note the order of `x` and `y` in the lambda.